# How to Set Capabilities on Node Browser with selenium Docker

Tags: docker, selenium-grid

I am new with selenium docker. I want to create a Chrome/Firefox node with capabilities (Selenium Grid). How to add capabilities when I add a Selenium Node docker container?
I found this command so far...

```
 docker run -d --link selenium-hub:hub selenium/node-firefox:2.53.0
```

but I don't know how to add capabilities on it. Already use this command but not working.

```
 docker run -d --link selenium-hub:hub selenium/node-firefox:2.53.0 -browser browserName=firefox,version=3.6,maxInstances=5,platform=LINUX
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing this and SE_OPTS is one of them, however for me it complicated what I was trying to accomplish. Using SE_OPTS forced me to set capabilities I didn't want to change, otherwise they would be reset to blank/null

I wanted to do:

```
SE_OPTS=-browser applicationName=Testing123
```

but I was forced to do:

```
SE_OPTS=-browser applicationName=Testing123,browserName=firefox,maxInstances=1,version=59.0.1
```

Another way to set capabilities is to supply your own config.json

```
-nodeConfig /path/config.json
```

You can find a [default config.json](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/server/src/org/openqa/grid/common/defaults/DefaultNodeWebDriver.json)

Or you can start the node container and copy the current one from it

```
docker cp <containerId>:/opt/selenium/config.json /host/path/target
```

You can also take a look at entry_point.sh, either on github or on the running container:

```
/opt/bin/entry_point.sh
```

You can run bash on the node container via:

```
sudo docker exec -i -t <container> bash
```

This will let you see how SE_OPTS is used and how config.json is generated. Note config.json is generated only if you don't supply one.

```
/opt/bin/generate_config
```

By examining generate_config you can see quite a few ENV vars such as:
FIREFOX_VERSION, NODE_MAX_INSTANCES, NODE_APPLICATION_NAME etc.

This leads to the third way to set capabilities which is to set the environment variables being used by generate_config, in my case APPLICATION_NODE_NAME

```
docker run -d -e "NODE_APPLICATION_NAME=Testing123"
```

Finally, when using SE_OPTS be careful not to accidentally change values. Specifically, the browser version. You can see by looking at entry_point.sh the browser version is calculated.

```
FIREFOX_VERSION=$( firefox -version | cut -d " " -f 3 )
```

If you change it to something else you will not get the results you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Solved... adding SE_OPTS will help you to set capabilites

```
docker run -d -e SE_OPTS="-browser browserName=chromeku,version=56.0,maxInstances=3,platform=WINDOWS" --link selenium-hub:hub selenium/node-chrome:2.53.0
```

Comment: ,Is there anyway to add acceptInsecureCerts via SE_OPTS . Did you tried this before?